# Opencart event data missing identifier

Tags: php, opencart

Using opencart 3 and trying to make use of the events but I'm unable to find the identifier.

E.g trying to extend the returns form added an event:

```
$this->model_setting_event->addEvent('mail_account_return_after', 'catalog/model/account/return/addReturn/after', 'extension/module/return/returnAdd');
```

Controller:

```
class ControllerExtensionModuleReturn extends Controller {

    public function returnAdd(&$route, &$args, &$output) {
        print_r($args);
        exit;
```

`$args` is missing the main return_id identifier:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => Foo
            [lastname] => Bar
            [email] => test@gmail.com
            [telephone] => 01234556789
            [order_id] => 29
            [date_ordered] => 2017-06-29
            [product] => Canon EOS 5D
            [model] => Product 3
            [quantity] => 1
            [return_reason_id] => 4
            [opened] => 0
            [comment] => Test comment
        )

)
```

Tried with `$this->db->getLastId()` but this returns 0. Tested with other events and appears to be missing the main identifiers.

Where does opencart set what data is passed to the before/after events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you should be able to access the auto increment `return_id` in `$output`, which holds the output of method `addReturn()`, i.e., `$this->db->getLastId();`.

As to why calling `getLastId()` a second time from within your event doesn't work, that's a good question.  I would assume there may be some other query happening in between - though by default I don't think there should be.  Is it possible there is another trigger running a query before your event gets triggered?

Answer (score 1):

Look in `system/engine/loader.php` at for the strings `before` and `after`.  There are methods that do view, controller, configuration and language.

Comment: Right I see how it works now coupled with Proxy and func_get_args it's just passing the original parameters.How would you get the return_id? Am not sure why getLastId is returning 0.

Comment: OpenCart 3.0 is very new, and this *might* be a bug.  Remember they introduced events in 2.0, changed in 2.3 and changed again in 3.0, so it might not be working perfectly.  Try posting in the OC forum.